# Windows 11 Hibernation file is taking 80% of the disk space

Tags: hibernate, storage

The hibernation file is taking 818GB of my 1TB disk. I have tried to disable it or reduce the size from command prompt and from regedit:

CMD:

`powercfg.exe /hibernate /size N`,

`powercfg -h off`,

regedit:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power`,

and changing `HibernateEnabledDefaultvalue` to 0

but it doesn't seem to do anything. When I try to change the size I get the message: "A device attached to the system is not functioning.".

Any suggestions are appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. How exactly did you try to reduce the size? Show the command you used, name the registry keys and values. How exactly did you check the size?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Bodo Done! Thanks.

Comment: You're saying that your hibernation file is taking 818 GB and that your hibernation file doesn't exist. That doesn't add up. How are you determining size of the hibernation file?

Comment: @gronostaj see the screenshot.

Comment: If the file was truly 818 GB, this wouldn't leave much of the disk for Windows and for you. The number seems too weird. Run `chkdsk` to verify. How much free space is available on the disk after running it?

Comment: @harrymc I have no space left on the disk. Barely 100MB.

Comment: How much is left after disabling hibernation? Note that `/hibernate /size 50` means 50% of the disk, which is enormous.

Comment: Disabling hibernation/changing size didn't change anything. When changing size I get "A device attached to the system is not functioning."

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). (don't forget `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc completed both operations. Nothing has changed!

Comment: Try to analyze the disk to see what takes up the space with a utility such as [JDiskReport](https://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/), and add its screenshot to your post. Add also a screenshot of the Disk Management screen. Check the SMART attributes of the disk with a utility such as [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy) and report if any errors are found.

Comment: @harrymc it shows that the hiberfil.sys file is occupying 818GB. I managed to show it in file explorer, but cannot delete it or reduce its size.

Comment: Did `chkdsk` do anything?

Comment: @gronostaj no, nothing

Comment: did you reboot after turning off hibernation?

Comment: @phuclv Yes, that didn't work until I enabled it again and then disabled it. Reboot wasn't need it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get rid of the `hiberfil.sys` file by first enabling and then disabling hibernation:

`powercfg -h on`

`powercfg -h off`.

Weird enough, it is still reporting "Hibernation file 818 GB" in the system settings, although the hard disk space is freed.

Thanks to everyone who posted an answer or commented.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Its a hidden and protected file. If you can not see the file, then how do you know its that large?  I think its unlikely that it is 818GB.

> The Hiberfil. sys hidden system file is located in the root folder of the drive where the operating system is installed. The Windows Kernel Power Manager reserves this file when you install Windows. The size of this file is approximately equal to how much random access memory (RAM) is installed on the computer.23 Sept 2021
> .

[From learn.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/disable-and-re-enable-hibernation)

Use the following commamds from Admin command shell or Powershell

`powercfg -h off`  Turns off hibernation and deletes the file.

`powercfg -h on`  Turns on hibernation

`powercfg hibernate size NN` Reduces the size. where NN is the percentsge size of memory. Note it may still have other items such as drivers stored in it.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with the `hiberfil.sys` file on the disk.

I suggest to disable hibernation with an elevated Command Prompt,
using the command:

```
powercfg -h off
```

If the `hiberfil.sys` file is still there, boot a Linux Live USB and
delete the file.

Reboot Windows and run immediately `chkdsk` to verify the disk.
If errors are found, run `chkdsk /f` to fix (but take backup of your
data before).

If everything passes fine, run:

```
powercfg -h on
```

If the file is still too large, reduce it to 10% if the disk by the command:

```
 powercfg.exe /hibernate /size 10
```

If the file is still too large, repeat the above process again.

If the file is still too large, then something is wrong with Windows.
To repair,
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html),
then repeat.